# How to give File access to Tableau server?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a .twb file created using the excel data source that is located in some network file path.

On publishing to server I get this error.

[image]

How to resolve this?

I need to provide some access for "Run as user" in my server machine,how could I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Ensure that when the workbook is created, a connection to the Excel file is created using the full UNC path
2. Ensure that the Tableau Server Run As user is able to access that file using the UNC path specified in the workbook. An easy way to test this would be to open Windows Explorer as the Run As user, then paste in the UNC path. If the Excel file opens, then you're good to go.

If you still have issues, test access to the file while logged into the Tableau server to make sure there is no firewall or port blocking access from that host. Often Excel isn't installed on servers for security reasons, so the test is not whether Excel opens the file, but whether you can view the contents from the server as the Run As User, even just using the type command at the console.

If you can't get your network access fixed, an alternative is to build and publish extracts to the server. There are multiple ways to accomplish that